# Display labels on one line and input on one line using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to recreate something like this using flexbox so that labels and inputs are on separate lines

[image: Screen Shot 2017-02-09 at 11.34.14.png]

```
            <form  class="form">
              <label> Credit Card Number </label>
              <input type="search" name="creditcard" placeholder="4831-0948-9417-4341">

              <label>Date</label>
              <input type="date" name="date">

              <label for="cvc">Cvc</label>
              <input type="text" name="cvc" placeholder="809">

            <label for="postcode">Zip</label>
            <input type="number" name="postcode" placeholder="94100">

              <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
```

http://codepen.io/o-sewell/pen/egPGYm?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

You mean like that?

```css
      .label {
        display: block;
      }

      .form {
        display: flex;
      }

      .cell{
        float: left;
      }
```

```html
<form  class="form">
  <div class="cell">
    <label> Credit Card Number </label></br>
    <input type="search" name="creditcard" placeholder="4831-0948-9417-4341">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <label>Date</label></br>
    <input type="date" name="date">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <label for="cvc">Cvc</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="cvc" placeholder="809">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <label for="postcode">Zip</label></br>
    <input type="number" name="postcode" placeholder="94100">
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you your answer helped me to figure it out :)

Comment: I like Your idea by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you i think i figured it out from your answer

```
<form  class="form">
              <div class="cell">
              <label> Credit Card Number </label>
              <input type="search" name="creditcard" placeholder="4831-0948-9417-4341">
              </div>
              <div class="cell">
              <label>Date</label>
              <input type="date" name="date">
              </div>
              <div class="cell">
              <label for="cvc">Cvc</label>
              <input type="text" name="cvc" placeholder="809">
              </div>
              <div class="cell">
              <label for="postcode">Zip</label>
              <input type="number" name="postcode" placeholder="94100">
              </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>


    form {
      display: flex;
    }

    .cell {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
    }
```